# Rails | Setting cookies according to user selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, storage

I would like to store user selected value on view on the cookies in rails.

So there would be 2 links as currencies, such as; euros and dollars. When user selects / clicks one of the links, it should update `cookies[:curr]`. Then the action should refresh the page with `redirect_to :back`

My problem is, I would like to add this option to footer. So user can access to this option anywhere on the web-site. But how can I change `cookies[:curr]` value when user selects on home page or any other controller?

I put below function to application controller to check the value of the `cookies[:curr]`

```
def return_currency
      if cookies[:curr].blank? || cookies[:curr].nil?
        '€' #default
      elsif cookies[:curr] == 'USD'
        '$'
   end
end
```

So here, I can check the value but, I could not figure it out how to assign an user selected value. Should it be a `form_for`? But then I can only send data to 1 controller, but I want user to access to any action as it will be at the footer.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A form might be sensible, as it would allow you to use a select, radio buttons or another field type to update the currency.

However, you could achieve this very simply by using a couple of link, such as the following.

In the view:

```
<%= link_to '€', your_currency_update_path(curr: '€') %>
```

In the controller:

```
def your_currency_update_action
  cookies[:curr] = params[:curr]
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Clicking this link will hit the controller passing the `params[:curr]` and redirect the user where they came from.

Or using a form like this:

```
<%= form_tag(your_currency_update_path, method: :post) do %>
  <%= select_tag :curr, options_for_select([['€'], ['$']) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Update Currency" %>
<% end %>
```

Finally, you could do away with the form's submit button by having it auto submit on change using the following:

```
<%= select_tag :curr, options_for_select([['€'], ['$']) %>, onchange: "this.form.submit();" %>
```

It doesn't matter which page this link / form is submitted from as it will always hit the controller action you choose to handle this, before redirecting back.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.